# SFMC query speed

Tags: marketing-cloud, sqlserver

I'm automating a bunch of queries and sends in SFMC and am curious about how long SQL queries take to run.
Is there a log where I can see the time taken for a query to finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best you can do is to add the query to an Automation in [Automation Studio](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/) or a [Program](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/programs/) in Interactions.  The execution start and end time is recorded in both.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks. I can run them and adjust timings to suit.